# Mouse wheel zoom setting for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to set it so that the mouse wheel zoom in Google Maps zooms more or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. I thought you might be able to by changing your mouse wheel's zoom in your operating system (Windows: Control Panel > Mouse > Wheel). However, I just tried it and it doesn't do anything either.

It seems that even in embedded maps, the [API only allows an enable/disable](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/04/v278-go-ahead-scroll-your-mouse-wheels.html). It doesn't have any settings related to it.

Answer (score 2):

In Map options, set the property

```
scrollwheel: false,
```

This should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if it’ll be different based on mouse settings or operating system, but when you double left click on your mouse it’ll zoom in, but if you double left click and hold it, then move your mouse up and down, it’ll zoom in and out.